# Find a function maximum with scipy.minimize

Tags: python, function, optimization, lambda, scipy-optimize-minimize

I´ve been asigned to find a given fuction´s maximum with scipy.minimize with the BFGS method using lambda. I´ve already figured out that in order to do that, I need to minimize the -(f) function, but I cannot change the function itself, only the way it´s called in the minimize. Also, the asnwer must be a float.

A abd B are the two functions to maximize

Thanks in advance for the help!!

```
def A(x):
 return -(x-1)**2

B = lambda x: -(x+2)**4 

#This is where the minimize is called
def argmax(f):
   from scipy.optimize import minimize
   
   return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `A` function must be sign inverted, create another function that calls `-A(x)`, for example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize

res = minimize(lambda t: -A(t), 0)
print(res.x[0])
```

which prints

```
0.9999999925496535
```

Similarly `B` must be flipped so that minimize finds the argmax of `B`:

```
res = minimize(lambda t: -A(t), 0)
print(res.x[0])
```

which prints

```
-1.987949853410927
```

Both of these answers are close to correct (expecting 1 and -2), although the result for B has fairly large error of 0.012.

The one-liner form for both maximizations (via minimizations) would be

```
return minimize(lambda t: -A(t), 0).x[0]
```

(and similarly for B)

To minimize both functions at the same time, create a function taking a vector:

```
return minimize(lambda v: -A(v[0])-B(v[1]), [0, 0]).x
```

which returns:

```
array([ 0.99999975, -1.98841637])
```

Comment: Note the starting guess ```0``` is arbitrary.  If you had a good guess to start with use that.

Comment: Thank you AbbeGijlym, you´ve helped a lot. I only have a couple more questions, how do I make this a one-liner in the return? and how do i make it calculate both functions at the same time?

Comment: @AndrésOrtega You're being really imprecise. What does "how do i[sic] make it calculate both functions at the same time?" Are you wanting to find the minimum of the product of the two functions? Run them in parallel?

Comment: @AndrésOrtega  : answer updated with one-liner form and one-liner *vector form for your amusement